# the template class in one header file cant find the other template class in another header file

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm trying to write a piece of code in c++ and to make things tidy I decided to split the source into files. So basically each header file contains the declarations for the class and its fields and methods and at the bottom, it includes a .cpp file with all the implementations. I had to do the quite bizarre act of including the source after the header because I'm using template classes and I had to do this to fix the linker error.

Anyway, the code looks something like this:

common/vec3.h:

```cpp
#ifndef
#define protector blah blah

template<class T>
class vec3{
//
// fields and methods
// int bruh
// double func(vec3<T>);
//
};
#include "vec3.cpp"
#endif
```

in common/vec3.cpp i only implement the functions declared in vec3.h:

```cpp
//=========vec3============

template <class T>
double vec3<T>::func(vec3<T> v){
//...
}
//...
```

common/dir3.h:

```cpp
#ifndef
#define protector blah blah

template<class T>
class dir3{
//
//
//
void operator=(vec3<T>); // this line is causing error
//
//
};
#include "dir3.cpp"
#endif
```

common/dir3.cpp:

```cpp
//======dir3===========
//
//
//
template<class T>
void dir3<T>::operator=(vec3<T> v){
// ...
}
//
//
```

in my main file i include these libraries like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
// ...
using namespace std;
#include "common/vec3.h"
#include "common/dir3.h"
// ...
int main(){
//...
}
```

but when I try to compile this project with

`g++ main.cpp -o main`

I get the error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:8:0:
common/dir3.h:14:17: error: 'vec3' is not a type
  void operator=(vec3<T>);
                 ^
```

even though I included `dir3.h` after `vec3.h` and they both have the template class definitions.
I know the nuances of the differences between classes and template classes to *some extent* but i can't see any other way to use a template class within another one(it doesnt need instantiating).

I even tried including the `vec3.h` file in the `dir3.h` file but it didn't work.

why isn't this working and what should I do?

Comment: Why are you including source files?!! Like you have in your given example `#include "dir3.cpp"` and `#include "vec3.cpp"`. You can refer to a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn the basics of templates and how to include/use them.

Comment: How should the files know each other without including them? BTW: Putting templated functions in cpp files will never work as long you did not manually instantiate them. Feels you should learn what is a translation unit, how to use templates and organizing a project into files...

Comment: Essential reading: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: I saw this solution on codeproject.com if I don't include the .cpp files and give them directly to g++ the vec3.cpp or the dir3.cpp never gets compiled because the instantiations take place somewhere else and the linker will give an error. @anoop-rana

Comment: @web_.junkie Yes, i know that site from where this solution that you're using comes from. I just have one thing to say about that which is that their given solution(s) are wrong. Don't include source files in your program as a best practice and also the solution that that particular site gives don't actually work and even if they work they result in undefined behavior. Refer to the duplicate that i linked to your question instead.

Comment: @Klaus i thought if i include eveything with the correct order in main.cpp it should be understandable. i even used g++ -Wall -C -E to check that they get included in the correct order.

Comment: @web_.junkie As a rule of thumb(or best practice) don't include source files.

Comment: I read that question before posting. as a matter of fact, the marked answer on that post has a solution almost identical to this(they used typename instead of class) that's what got me confused to ask this here. @anoop-rana